# Passing arguments to superclass

Tags: java

Hey guy's i'm trying to use a constructor to accept a ton of variables and then pass the relevant information to the superclass constructor.

The error im getting is that when i use this.variable it's telling me to create that variable in the class, but i thought calling the super would allow me to use it this way.

```
public class AuctionSale extends PropertySale {

private String highestBidder;   
public AuctionSale(String saleID, String propertyAddress, int reservePrice, String    highestBidder) {
    super(saleID, propertyAddress, reservePrice);
    this.saleID = saleID;
    this.propertyAddress = propertyAddress;
    this.reservePrice = reservePrice;
    this.highestBidder = "NO BIDS PLACED";
}
```

As you can see i've called the superclass propertysale to get the variables.

Superclass -

```
public class PropertySale {
// Instance Variables
private String saleID;
private String propertyAddress;
private int reservePrice;
private int currentOffer;
private boolean saleStatus = true;

public PropertySale(String saleID, String propertyAddress, int reservePrice) {
    this.saleID = saleID;
    this.propertyAddress = propertyAddress;
    this.reservePrice = reservePrice;
}
```

There is a lot more additional constructors but i believe they are irrelevant right now.

Comment: cab you post your super class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that you get the error is because the following variables have `private` access in the `PropertySale` class:

```
saleID
propertyAddress
reservePrice
```

You cannot access them in the subclass `AuctionSale` unless the superclass declares them `protected` or `public`. However, in this case it is not necessary: you pass these three variables to the `super` constructor, so they get set in the base class. All you need in the constructor of the derived class is to call `super`, and then deal with variables that the derived class has declared, like this:

```
public AuctionSale(String saleID, String propertyAddress, int reservePrice, String    highestBidder) {
    super(saleID, propertyAddress, reservePrice);
    this.highestBidder = "NO BIDS PLACED";
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly as dasblinkenlight has written it. Also, you don't need to specify "this."; you can just do `highestBidder = "No bids placed"` and it will work fine. Most of the time, "this." is only needed to disambiguate a class member from a local variable.

Answer (score 4):

The private variables can only be accessed in the class where they are declared, no where else. Protected or public variables can be accessed in subclass.

**In any way what's the use of passing the variables of the class to its own constructor?**

Your `saleID`,`propertyAddress`,`reservePrice` are all private variables in super class. That restricts the usage.

You are however setting the variables through superclass' constructor so you do not have to set it yourself....

```
public class AuctionSale extends PropertySale {

private String highestBidder;   
public AuctionSale(String saleID, String propertyAddress, int reservePrice, String    highestBidder) {
    super(saleID, propertyAddress, reservePrice);//This should be sufficient
    //this.saleID = saleID;
    //this.propertyAddress = propertyAddress;
    //this.reservePrice = reservePrice;
    this.highestBidder = "NO BIDS PLACED";
}
```

If you want to access private variables, best practice is to write `getter` and `setter` methods in super class and use them wherever you want.

Answer (score 2):

You have marked the variables in super class as private which means they won't be inherited.mark them as public,default,or protected and test.Private fields are only visible in the class itself.